# C++ Class Composition: Constructor? or ()operator?

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-keyword, composition

I was writing a code for a book exercise and ran into a simple question. It would be best if I show the examples first.

- First class: fClass heaader

  ```
  class fClass
  {
  public:
      explicit fClass( int = 0, int = 0 );
      fClass& operator()( int, int );
      void print();
  private:
      int x;
      int y;
  }
  ```
- First class: fClass cpp

  ```
  fClass::fClass( int a, int b )
  : x(a), y(b)
  {
  }
  fClass& fClass::operator()( int a, int b )
  {
      x = a;
      y = b;
  }
  void fClass::print()
  {
      cout << "x: " << x << "\ny: " << y << endl;
  }
  ```
- Second class, sClass.h

  ```
  class sClass
  {
  public:
      explicit sClass( int = 0, int = 0 );
      void print();
  private:
      fClass firstClass;
  }
  ```
- Second class, sClass.cpp

  ```
  sClass::sClass( int a, int b )
  : firstClass( a, b )
  {
  }
  void sClass::print()
  {
      firstClass.print();
  }
  ```
- The main function

  ```
  int main()
  {
      sClass secondClass( 1, 2 );
      secondClass.print();
  }
  ```

Now my question is when I deleted the operator() function in fClass. The code still worked! As I understand the 'explicit' declaration of fClass's constructor should prohibit sClass's fClass definition in its constructor (firstClass( a, b )) because fClass was already explicitly defined in private member declaration. Therefore, to re-initialize it in sClass as firstClass( a, b ), operator function () should be defined (as I did). Why would this code work without operator() definition?

To add more comments on my question, to my understanding, the statement 'firstClass( a, b )' should not call the fClass's explicit constructor, because it is not the first time it is initialized. Again, to my understanding, constructors are called when a class is first initialized to construct the class. firstClass is already initialized and constructed in header file...

Comment: Just for your info, the `class` when defining instances `class sClass secondClass(1,2)` is redundant, similarly for `enum`, `union`, `struct`. Then, none of this requires five files. When extracting an example, try to put everything in one file and inline it, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confused about the `explicit` keyword and `operator()` functions.

The keyword `explicit` prevents the constructor from getting called to construct an object implicitly. Simple example:

Let's say there is a function:

```
void foo(fClass obj) {...}
```

**Without** the `explicit` keyword, you will be able to call the function using the syntax:

```
foo({1, 2});
```

The arugment `{1,2}` will be used to call the constructor and resulting object will be passed to `foo`.

**With** the `explicit` keyword, you won't be able to use that. You'll have to use:

```
foo(fClass{1, 2});
```

or

```
foo(fClass(1, 2));
```

The `operator()` function has no relationship with the `explicit` keyword and construction of objects. It simply means, you can use:

```
fClass obj(1, 2);
obj(10, 20);
```

You said:

> As I understand the `explicit` declaration of `fClass`'s constructor should prohibit `sClass`'s `fClass` definition in its constructor (`firstClass( a, b )`) because `fClass` was already explicitly defined in private member declaration.

Your understanding is not correct.

The line

```
fClass firstClass;
```

in the definition of class `sClass` simply says that the class has a member variable named `firstClass` and its type is `fClass`. It doesn't set the value of the variable when an object of `sClass` is constructed.

In the definition of the constructor of `sClass`, you are initializing the member using `: firstClass( a, b )`, which is the right thing to do. If you skipped it, the member will be initialized as if you used `:firstClass()`, which is a valid way to initialize an object of type `fClass`.

Comment: @R Sahu: Thank you so much for your explanation. I now have a better understanding in implicit and explicit. I guess your answer also answers my question in Matt McNabb's comment: "So does this mean a class can be re-initialized even after it's declaration? meaning after I do 'sClass secondClass;' then I can do 'secondClass(int 1, int 2);' in main()? Or does this only applies in initialization such as 'sClass::sClass( int a, int b ): firstClass( a, b )'?" So this will not be allowed outside of sClass constructor. Am I correct?

Comment: No, you cannot use  `secondClass(int 1, int 2);` in `main` or anywhere else. That statement is wrong on multiple accounts.

Answer (score 2):

The code:

```
sClass::sClass( int a, int b )
    : firstClass( a, b )
```

means that the `firstClass` subobject will have its constructor called which takes `a` and `b`.  `explicit` constructors are considered for this usage, and `operator()` is unrelated.

Your code does not invoke `operator()` anywhere so it is no surprise that deleting it makes no difference. That operator is used when the name of a variable is used in an expression, followed by parentheses.

Comment: @ Matt McNabb: Thank you for the explanation. So does this mean a class can be re-initialized even after it's declaration? meaning after I do 'sClass secondClass;' then I can do 'secondClass(int 1, int 2);'? Or does this only applies in initialization such as 'sClass::sClass( int a, int b ): firstClass( a, b )'?

Comment: @GrinNare class constructors can only be called once per object, at the point of construction.  `secondClass(1, 2);` calls the `()` operator.

Comment: @ Matt McNabb: Thank you so much for your answers. It's really sad I can only pick one answer. Learning without teacher or professor is extremely difficulty...  ;( Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `explicit` only prevents cases where an object could be converted by passing it to a function. Yours is not such a case. I have no idea where that `operator()` overload should have any influence, maybe if you gave the URL to the text that claimed this, people here could decipher the real meaning (or the lack thereof) for you.